# PHPでhrefの値の置換

Tags: php, html, 正規表現

以下のようなhtmlがあり、その中のhrefの値を全て、$urlに置換するにはどのような処理を行えばいいでしょうか？

詳しい方、ご教示ください。宜しくお願い致します。

```
<div class="article_image"><a href="http://www.amazon.co.jp/PENTAX-%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC-%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88-STANDARD-06239/dp/B00MFD07OO/ref=sr_1_1/375-7893352-7638937?ie=UTF8&qid=1457086894&sr=8-1&keywords=Q-S1"><img class="article_img" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Rs3BwRg2L._AA160_.jpg" /></a></div><div class="article_image_text article_product_info"><p class="article_product_brand"><a href="http://www.amazon.co.jp/PENTAX-%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC-%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88-STANDARD-06239/dp/B00MFD07OO/ref=sr_1_1/375-7893352-7638937?ie=UTF8&qid=1457086894&sr=8-1&keywords=Q-S1">PENTAX ミラーレス一眼 Q-S1 ズームレンズキット [標準ズーム 02 STANDARD ZOOM] ゴールド 06239</a></p><p class="article_product_price">￥ 28,205 </p><div class="btn_item_area clearfix"><a href="http://www.amazon.co.jp/PENTAX-%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC-%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88-STANDARD-06239/dp/B00MFD07OO/ref=sr_1_1/375-7893352-7638937?ie=UTF8&qid=1457086894&sr=8-1&keywords=Q-S1" target="_blank" class="btn_item btn_shop">サイトで購入</a></div>
```

Comment: タグは一つだけなのですか？hrefの値にかかわらず$urlの値に置換したいのですか？…前回の質問も踏まえると、複数のaタグを含んだhtmlに対してAmazonのURLをすべて正規化したい、ということはないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

HTMLのタグが文字列であるということですか？
`$html_code`にタグが格納されているとして下記のように置き換えればいいと思います。

```
$url = '置き換えたい文字列';
$html_code = '<div class="article_image"><a href="http://www.amazon.co.jp/～中略～&keywords=Q-S1" target="_blank" class="btn_item btn_shop">サイトで購入</a></div>';
$output = preg_replace("/(<a href=\").*?(\".*?>)/", "$1$url$2", $html_code);
echo $output;
```

Comment: できないようです、、。何か原因は考えられますでしょうか。

Comment: 置換が全く何も行われていないようです。
質問ですが、以下の変数はどこから出てきたのでしょうか？
$1 $2
ご返答頂けますと、幸いです。

Comment: 正規表現時のグループ`()`でくくられた文字列は$1から連番で振られます。`preg_replace`の使い方はご存知ですか？この命令の出力を変数に代入して使います。代入部分をもう少し詳しく記載しました。

Comment: また、出来ない場合、どのように記載し、どう結果が出力されたのかを質問文を編集して明記してください。現状ですと、どういったミスをしてらっしゃるのかが分かりません。

Answer (score 0):

変数`$url`でhrefの中身を置換すればよいのですか。

```
<?php

// your code goes here

$html = '<div class="article_image"><a title="test" href=\'http://www.amazon.co.jp/PENTAX-%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC-%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88-STANDARD-06239/dp/B00MFD07OO/ref=sr_1_1/375-7893352-7638937?ie=UTF8&qid=1457086894&sr=8-1&keywords=Q-S1\'><img class="article_img" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Rs3BwRg2L._AA160_.jpg" /></a></div><div class="article_image_text article_product_info"><p class="article_product_brand"><a href="http://www.amazon.co.jp/PENTAX-%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC-%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88-STANDARD-06239/dp/B00MFD07OO/ref=sr_1_1/375-7893352-7638937?ie=UTF8&qid=1457086894&sr=8-1&keywords=Q-S1">PENTAX ミラーレス一眼 Q-S1 ズームレンズキット [標準ズーム 02 STANDARD ZOOM] ゴールド 06239</a></p><p class="article_product_price">￥ 28,205 </p><div class="btn_item_area clearfix"><a href="http://www.amazon.co.jp/PENTAX-%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC-%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88-STANDARD-06239/dp/B00MFD07OO/ref=sr_1_1/375-7893352-7638937?ie=UTF8&qid=1457086894&sr=8-1&keywords=Q-S1" target="_blank" class="btn_item btn_shop">サイトで購入</a></div>';
$url = 'http://example.com/';

$result = preg_replace(
    // regexp
    '/(<a.*?href=(?:\'|"))([^\'"]+?)((?:\'|").*?>)/',
    // replacement
    '$1' . $url . '$3',
    // input
    $html
);

echo $result;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ad18c9538f82e45fda5c5627ece4df188edb33a

hrefの中身ごとに置換処理をカスタマイズする場合は[preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.preg-replace-callback.php)を検討してみてください。
`$1`についてはphpのドキュメントあるいはhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888417/などをご参照ください。